# SQL SELECT name by id

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I need help with a sql query.

I have these 2 tables:

`player_locations:`

```
ID |  playerid  | location <- unqiue key
---|-----------------------
 1 |    1       | DOWNTOWN
```

and `users:`

```
ID  | playername | [..]
----|--------------------
 1  | example1   | ...
```

I need a select to get the `users.playername` from the `player_locations.playerid`. I have the unique location to get the `player_locations.playerid`.

Pseudo query:

```
SELECT playername 
FROM users
WHERE id = player_locations.playerid 
  AND player_locations.location = "DOWNTOWN";
```

The output should be `example1`.

Comment: `FROM users` should be `FROM users, player_locations`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is just a simple `INNER JOIN`. The general syntax for a [**JOIN**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) is:

```
SELECT stuff
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.relatedColumn = table2.relatedColumn
```

In your case, you can relate the two tables using the `id` column from users and `playerid` column from `player_locations`. You can also include your `'DOWNTOWN'` requirement in the `JOIN` statement. Try this:

```
SELECT u.playername
FROM users u
JOIN player_locations pl ON pl.playerid = u.id AND pl.location = 'DOWNTOWN';
```

**EDIT**

While I personally prefer the above syntax, I would like you to be aware of another way to write this which is similar to what you have now.

You can also select from multiple tables by using a comma in your `FROM` clause to separate them. Then, in your `WHERE` clause you can insert your conditions:

```
SELECT u.playername
FROM users u, player_locations pl
WHERE u.id = pl.playerid AND pl.location = 'DOWNTOWN';
```

Comment: SQL is never easy in the beginning. Keep working hard, and you'll solve problems like these in no time after a while. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution.

```
SELECT
playername
FROM users
WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM player_locations WHERE location='DOWNTOWN')
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a idea, try this:

```
SELECT playername 
FROM users
WHERE id IN (SELECT DISTINCT playerid FROM player_location WHERE location LIKE "DOWNTOWN");
```